# Can't get values from Backendless table on javascript

Tags: javascript, backendless

I have the table "Products" with full fields. I try to find and get values with some condition. This is javascript file

```
var APPLICATION_ID = "id",
SECRET_KEY = "key",
VERSION = "v1"; 

Backendless.initApp(APPLICATION_ID, SECRET_KEY, VERSION);

function Products(args) {
    args = args || {};
    this.id_user = args.id_user || "";
    this.cal = args.cal || null;
    this.id_day = args.id_day || null;
    this.id_product = args.id_product || null;
    this.nameProduct = args.nameProduct || "";
}

var productStorage = Backendless.Persistence.of( Products );

var query = { 
    condition : "id_day = 33"
}

function get(){
    try{
        var product = productStorage.find(query).data;
    }catch( e )
    {
        if( e.code != 1009 )
        alert(e.message);
    }

    return [];
}


var array = get();
alert(array[0]);
```

in alert message i get just "undefined". And also there are no problems in catch block in the function "get()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Backendless team, they helped me to solve this. So my code :

```
var APP_ID = "id",
SECRET_KEY = "key",
VERSION = "v1"; 

function Products(args) {
    args = args || {};
    this.id_user = args.id_user || "";
    this.cal = args.cal || null;
    this.id_day = args.id_day || null;
    this.id_product = args.id_product || null;
    this.nameProduct = args.nameProduct || "";
}

var dataQuery = {
   condition: "id_day = 33"
};

function fetchingFirstPageAsync(){

    var products = Backendless.Persistence.of(Products).find(dataQuery);

    for(var i = 0; i < products.data.length; i++) {
        console.log("Product name = " + products.data[i].nameProduct);
    }
}

Backendless.initApp( APP_ID, SECRET_KEY, VERSION );
fetchingFirstPageAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're always returning an empty array, even if your query finds a product - an empty array has nothing in index '0', therefore you get 'undefined'.

Try adding

```
return product;
```

to get(), right after you query for it.

Debugging will be easier with `console.log` instead of `alert` - you'll need to open your browser's javascript console to see it:

```
console.log(array)
```

If you do choose to use `alert`, converting the value to JSON can help:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: it seems that your answer is right, but i get that "undefined" anyway.. seems that i am wrong with the query or working with Backendless..

Comment: So,  i tried change code `product= productStorage.find(query);` and wrote `var array = get();
console.log(array);` and i got "response: ".... class":"Products","id_user":"333","ownerId":null......" in XMLHttpRequest{} in console. It is what i need to get. So there is exist my information, but how to get it from responce?

Comment: Full response is  `response: "{"offset":0,"data":[{"id_day":"33","id_product":null,"created":145....00,"___class":"Products","id_user":"333","ownerId":null,"updated":14....000,"nameProduct":"iris","objectId":"DE8....4F00","cal":null,"__meta":"{\"relationRemovalIds\":{},\"selectedProperties\":[\"id_day\",\"id_product\",\"created\",\"___class\",\"id_user\",\"ownerId\",\"updated\",\"nameProduct\",\"objectId\",\"cal\"],\"relatedObjects\":{}}"}],"nextPage":null,"totalObjects":1}"`